# How do I get the "image-pointing" arrow to appear in a sliding carousel, as illustrated?

Tags: html, css, controls, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel for my website.

How would I get the image-pointing arrow to appear with the corresponding image when it slides into the carousel view? Here is an illustration of what I want.

All the relevant bootstrap links are in place in the `<head>` section of the document.

Here is the code I have so far;

```
<div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
    <div class="triangle" id="tri-2"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" id="center-left" data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1">
        <div class="inner-text-box">This year's ISA account<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
<div class="triangle" id="tri-3"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" id="center-right" data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="3">
        <div class="inner-text-box">Current Accounts<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
<div class="triangle" id="tri-4"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" data-target="'slider" data-slide-to="4">
        <div class="inner-text-box">Savings Accountss<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container{
width:25%;
float:left;
cursor:pointer;
background-color:#E0DDDD;
position:relative;
}
.menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container:hover{
background-color:#0D0155;
color:white;
}
.triangle{
width:0px;
height:0px;
border:transparent solid 20px;
border-bottom:#0D0155 solid 20px;
display:none;
padding:0px;
margin-left:100px;
bottom:99%;
position:absolute;
}
.menu-cascading-image-button{
float:left;
cursor:pointer;
width:100%;
}
#menu-button-container{
width:100%;
}
.inner-text-box{
font-size:15px;
color:#0D0155;
padding:15px;
font-weight:200;
}
.inner-text-box i{
float:right;
padding-top:3px;
font-weight:100;
}
.inner-text-box:hover{
color:white;
}
```

Thanks

[image: Bottom carousel controls with arrow]

Comment: use image or send code if you want it with the help of code

Comment: Thanks, just added the HTML & CSS code to the post. The arrows are in place but they need to move when the relevant image slides into the carousel view. Thanks, T.

Answer (score 0):

They won't move as they are independent for independent carousel Item.

Actual trick will work when there is only one element for all items of carousel.  And with JS, you can move the element depending upon which element is active.

Following code illustrates that. Click on items to see it moving. This is simple example and would need to be enhanced to make it work in complex arrangements.

```js
var container = '.menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container';
var item = '.menu-cascading-image-button';
var triangle = '#triangle';
var triangleWidth = $(triangle).outerWidth();

function markActive(elementToGo) {
  $el = $(elementToGo);
  $(item).removeClass('active');
  $el.addClass('active');
  var offset = $el.position();
  var width = $el.outerWidth();
  var left = width / 2 - triangleWidth / 2;
  $(triangle).css('margin-left', left + offset.left);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  //initial page load
  markActive(item + ':first');
  
  //mark item active on click
  $(item).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    markActive(this)
  })

})
```

```css
.menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container .menu-cascading-image-button {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #E0DDDD;
  color: #0D0155;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container .menu-cascading-image-button.last {
  border-right-color: transparent;
}
.menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container .menu-cascading-image-button.active,
.menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container .menu-cascading-image-button:hover {
  background-color: #0D0155;
  color: white;
}
.menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container[data-active] .triangle {
  display: block
}
.triangle {
  transition: margin linear 0.3s;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: transparent solid 20px;
  border-bottom: #0D0155 solid 20px;
  display: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  bottom: 99%;
  position: absolute;
}
#menu-button-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.inner-text-box {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.inner-text-box i {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container" data-active>
  <div class="triangle" id="triangle"></div>
  <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" id="center-left" data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1">
    <div class="inner-text-box">This year's ISA account<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" id="center-right" data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="3">
    <div class="inner-text-box">Current Accounts<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-cascading-image-button last" data-target="'slider" data-slide-to="4">
    <div class="inner-text-box">Savings Accountss<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```